# "anything less than whole”

Tags: meaning-in-context, poetry

Hey can someone help me to explain what does "anything less than whole” in this poem by Rupi Kaur mean?

> i had to leave
>   i was tired of
>   allowing you to
>   make me feel
>   **anything less
>
>   than whole**

[image: picture of the poem]

Comment: Hi, welcome! In order to answer better, could you add a little more describing what you think it means and where you get confused? Thanks.

Comment: Do you already know what 'feeling whole' means? 'feeling anything less than whole' would be the negation of that. "Like a part of me is missing".

Answer (score 1):

In my assumption **"anything less than whole"** would mean that the author was treated **poorly (*less*)** or was not treated with or was given her **full respect (*whole*)**.

Here less doesn't essentially mean poor but to some [words](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/less) like limited,lower,negative,deficient,diminished,as expected,lacking,not as great,reduced
and [whole](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/whole?s=t) would mean perfect,aggregate,completed,fulfilled,in one piece

May be she was put down by Mr.S many at times which made her to get tired and sad. Eventually when she could take no more of this (attitude of Mr.S) she decided to leave.